# macOS Mojave Beach Ball when saving a file

Tags: high-sierra, performance, mojave, macos

When I'm trying to save or select a file in a web browser, or any other application the beachball appears and the app hangs for ±30 seconds.

I didn't have this problem in High Sierra. Is it a common bug or specific to my hardware?
I have MacBook Pro Retina 15 2014

Comment: I don't have this problem and I'm running Mojave.  Try the usual troubleshooting routine of doing an SMC reset, test if it happens; if so, try creating a new user and testing again.

Comment: Same problem, same MacBook... I've tried all kinds of SMC and PRAM resets to no avail...

Answer (score 3):

Found it. SMC reset didn't fix it. It's an iCloud issue. One solution is to remove the iCloud tab from the finder sidebar through Finder->Preferences->Sidebar.

It's not perfect, but at least productivity is back. I hope they will run an update that will solve this.

Peter

Answer (score 2):

I have the same setup and had the exact same problem, which I somehow got resolved. Now I'm not sure what exactly worked out of everything I tried, but here's the list:

- Disabled dynamic wallpaper
- SMC/PRAM reset
- Checked login items and deleted a few (had for example Magnet and BetterSnapTool both starting on login and also some other weird processes)

Good luck finding the culprit.

Comment: @fsb What's wrong with this?

Comment: @JBis Nothing, I must've hit the wrong button for the auto-text comment.  Thanks for pointing it out, I'll delete it.